# How can I get the current date in BUILD.bazel file

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules, bazel-aspect, bazel-cpp

I am new to bazel and facing the below issue while building my CPP code with bazel.

I want to pass the current date as one of the local defines in the below format.

date =  < rule to get current date >

cc_lib(
... ,
local_define = [ "xyz = 28-11-2022"],
)

how can I get the current date every time I run the bazel build?
local_define = [ "xyz = date"],

I tried loading the python date but starlark doesn't have support for that.

Comment: Can you elabrate why you need such a date? Put a date in CPP file defintely not a good idea in Bazel, it just causes the build cache can't be hit.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way that bazel handles non-deterministic information in the build is using "build stamping", described here:

https://bazel.build/docs/user-manual#workspace-status

Bazel goes to great lengths to avoid non-determinism because it's bad for caching, so adding something like the current time to a build isn't straight forward. Using build stamping sometimes requires changing your program or generating files based on the `status.txt` files and incorporating those into your build. If defines are really needed, you can do that with something like this:

`BUILD`:

```
cc_binary(
  name = "main",
  srcs = ["main.c"],
  local_defines = ["DATE=\"$(DATE)\""],
)
```

`main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef DATE
#define DATE "none"
#endif

int main() {
  printf("date is %s\n", DATE);
  return 0;
}
```

```
$ bazel build main --define DATE="\\\"$(date)\\\""
INFO: Analyzed target //:main (37 packages loaded, 163 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //:main up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/main
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.497s, Critical Path: 0.08s
INFO: 6 processes: 4 internal, 2 linux-sandbox.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 6 total actions

$ bazel-bin/main
date is Mon Nov 28 04:33:30 PM EST 2022
```

(All the escaping is necessary to allow for spaces in the date, but you might not need all that.)

Note that the `--define DATE="\\\"$(date)\\\""` must be provided on the command line, and can't be put into a `.bazelrc` because `.bazelrc` isn't evaluated like the shell.

Comment: This definitely works, however, it causes a full-build and won't hit any cache, as the date changes frequently...